# How to read text files from sub directory in scala

Tags: scala

i have sub directory under resources (Memory)

- src

  - test

    - resources

      - Memory

where i put all my text files, i know how to read file from resources directly with:

```
val sdf = "file1.txt"  
val file:File = new File("file1.txt")
  ....
```

but using sub directory i dont know how. i am trying to do something like

```
val path = scala.reflect.io.Path("src/test/resources/Memory/file1.txt")
```

but i get java.lang.NullPointerException: null

Comment: What do you mean ? `scala.reflect.io.Path("src/test/resources/Memory/file1.txt")` returns null (so later you get a NPE) ? or this line is throwing NPE ?

Comment: i try first just to know if i have access to my directory so i do: val lines = Source.fromFile(path).getLines
  lines.foreach(line => println(line))

Comment: i mean i would like to print the content of one file

Comment: `new File("Memory/file1.txt")`

Comment: its not working, now i try another solution like : val data= getClass.getResourcesAsStream (name="/Memory/")  ;;; val lines= Source.fromInputStream (data).getLines  ;;;;    lines.foreach(line => println(line);;; but that gives me just the name of all files under Memory like(test1.txt, test2.txt). when i make val data= getClass.getResourcesAsStream (name="/Memory/test1.tx") i get java.lang.NullPointerException: null